# ASN 1 : before or after signature?

Tags: asn.1

Assume that there is a specific ASN 1 representation for a specific message in a standard. But the question is that we have to **first** sign this message and **then** do encoding according ASN 1 or we have to **first** convert to ASN 1 and **then** sign it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: downvote b/c this question is not going to be helpful to others since it depends on some specification that isn't being shared.

Comment: @Kevin, but I think the sequence of encoding and signature is a general rule in all of standards.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application, but the common practice is to format message in ASN and then sign resulting ASN structure. It would look as follows:

```
SignedMessage           ::= SEQUENCE {
   tbsData              ToBeSignedData,
   signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier {SIGNATURE-ALGORITHM,
                            {sa-dsaWithSHA1 | sa-rsaWithSHA1 |
                                 sa-rsaWithMD5 | sa-rsaWithMD2, ...}},
   signature            BIT STRING,
   certs            [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
}
```

this means that the signature is calculated over `tbsData` structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful answer. But in fact there is some confusion yet that I can't understand, I can send you related standard's document, but the problem is that the documents are confidential and I can't publish it in public. So, I am so grateful to you if you could grant me an email address to send related documents that is only 5-7 pages. Really I appreciate your help.

Comment: Find my web site in the profile page and use email link under avatar (on my website) to contact me.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I sent you a message including related documents and code.